# Fonts without bold, italic XeLaTex

Tags: fonts, xetex

I was trying to use Quimera font (a free OTF serif font) with XeLaTeX but this font have no italic nor bold versions. Then appears some issues in warnings messages

```
Package fontspec Info: Font family 'Quimera.otf(0)' created for font
(fontspec)             'Quimera.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [Ligatures=TeX,AutoFakeBold=1.2,AutoFakeSlant=0.15].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[Quimera.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[Quimera.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;embolden=1.2;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[Quimera.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;slant=0.15;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[Quimera.otf]/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;embolden=1.2;slant=0.15;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:


.
.
.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 15.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.

.
.
.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/Quimera(0)/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/Quimera(0)/m/it' instead on input line 25.

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 7963 strings out of 479712
 169734 string characters out of 5889204
 588753 words of memory out of 5000000
 25169 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 535152 words of font info for 37 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 37i,11n,67p,240b,233s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
```

I'm on Overleaf and no errors appear. The problem is that the `pdf` is not generated. I guess I'm forgetting something. Its possible work with this font in XeLaTeX?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Quimera.otf}
[
  AutoFakeBold=1.2,
  AutoFakeSlant=0.15,
]
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\savegeometry{Mem}
\newgeometry{margin=0pt}
%\lipsum[1-10]
    Quimera
%\clearpage
%\loadgeometry{Mem}
%\lipsum[11-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Real quick: Why are you loading the `lmodern` font package?

Comment: `\setromanfont` should be `\setmainfont`. Your `BoldFont=` and `ItalicFont=` options are commented out. Is this intentional? Are there bold and italic font faces in the directory? What are their filenames?

Comment: the warning in itself is not an issue it just tells you what you told us: that the font doesn't have the variant styles, specifically that warning says if you use `\slshape` to get slanted latex will just give the normal upright as there is no slanted.

Comment: @Davislor there are no bold nor italic faces.

Comment: I added information. The problem is the pdf is not generated.

Comment: @juanuni In that case, you might try the options `AutoFakeBold=1.2, AutoFakeSlant = 0.15` to fake them.

Comment: @juanuni: Can you provide a link to the project on Overleaf? We don't have access to the Quimera font.

Comment: @Davislor with your suggestion ocurrs some changes (look the update in question) but the problem still ocurrs.

Comment: @Werner your overleaf id?

Comment: @juanuni: My suggestion was general, as I'm not well-versed in terms of fonts to answer this question directly. If you provide a link to the project so the general public who sees this problem can use that to replicate the problem, then they can help you.

Comment: @Werner Oh ok, here is the link https://www.overleaf.com/2345959183mwhgpbqhwpsw

Comment: `AutoFakeBold` and `AutoFakeSlant` only work if you give numbers. Take another look at my example.

Comment: @Davislor you mean `\setmainfont{Quimera.otf}[AutoFakeBold=1.2, AutoFakeSlant=0.15,]` ? ... the problem is still there, some things changes in log file but `pdf` is not yet generated. I added some information from `log` file

Comment: @juanuni The issue is not with your document, the font has some odd properties which trigger a bug in `xdvipdfmx` (the program which generates the PDF files for XeLaTeX documents). Therefore you can't use this font in XeLaTeX until this bug gets fixed. Until then, I recommend switching to LuaLaTeX. There your document works correctly.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger oh, I see. You're right. Is a font design problem?

Comment: @juanuni It's not exactly design specific, it's rather technical: OTF/CFF fonts like this contain a "Private" table which contains some metadata (Mostly for hinting). In your font, this table is empty. That's allowed, but very uncommon and `xdvipdfmx` in one place forgets to handle this case correctly.

Comment: I will like try with another fonts like this, without bold and italic styles. I assume that I may run into similar problems in the future.

Comment: @juanuni It doesn't matter if your font has bold and italic styles. If you don't use very unusual fonts you shouldn't encounter this issue often. Anyway I would just switch to Lua latex, then the issue disappears and it's a better engine anyway IMO.